# Is the term "carboreduction" interchangeable with "carbothermic reduction"?

Tags: redox, terminology

I am currently studying reactions involving the reduction of metal oxides by carbon at high temperature to produce refractory carbides (such as $\ce{ZrC}$) following equations such as:

$$
\ce{ZrO2 + 3C -> ZrC + 2CO (g)}
$$

I have come across both the following terms for this type of a reaction `carbothermic reduction` and `carboreduction`; they appear to be used completely interchangeably. I would like to make sure (as I have not yet found a source to say otherwise) that this is the case in chemistry terminology and not that one may be applied to an equation as above and the other to a similar reaction where the product is actually the pure reduced metal, such as that for iron ore smelting:

$$
\ce{2Fe2O3 + 3C -> 4Fe + 3CO2}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "carboreduction" has an [IUPAC definition:](http://goldbook.iupac.org/CT07609.html)

> Process in which a metal oxide is reduced in the presence of carbon or a carbon-containing compound.

So technically the term does not require heating and isn't limited to elemental carbon.

Carbothermic definitely implies heating.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, it does make sense, have a good day